# Not able Invoke controller action method from Ajax Jquery

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I was trying to call mvc core action method from ajax but getting error in console:

Following are the code:
`

```
$.ajax({
        url: LogOutUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Done");
                if (window.location.href.indexOf(EserviceLogOutUrl) === -1) {
                    window.location.href = EserviceLogOutUrl;
                }
            } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
```

MVC:

MVC: Controller:

```
public ActionResult Signout()
        {
            foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
            }
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Clear();
            return new RedirectResult("http://Google.com");//Redirecting to different website in antoher domain.
        }
```

Error in console: I am able to invoke the action methods. but not able redirect the URL.

SEC7123: Request header x-requested-with was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.

Answer (score 0):

Add a header to options to satisfy your server:

```js
$.ajax({
        url: LogOutUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        ...
```